# C programming: ouput two strings as two columns next to each other

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, multiple-columns

I have a question regarding an issue with a program in C I am making. I am going to write two different strings next to each other in two columns. I haven't found clear answers to my question since they almost always give examples of numbers with a known length or amount.

I have two strings, with a maximum length of 1500 characters, but to me unknown length. Let's for the sake of learning given them these values:

```
char string1[] = "The independent country is not only self-governed nation with own authorities.";
char string2[] = "This status needs the international diplomatic recognition of sovereignty.";
```

I want to write them next to each other, with a column width of twenty characters. I have set the difference between the columns to a regular 'tab'. Like this:

```
The independent coun     This status needs th
try is not only self     e international dipl
-governed nation wit     omatic recognition o
h own authorities.       f sovereignty.
```

I have tried with the following code but it isn't effective since I can't figure out how to adapt it to the length of the strings. It also just adapted to write five rows. I also get the below error.

Could someone please give me an example of how this could be done, and maybe with a pre-defined c-function in order to avoid using the for-loops.

```
void display_columns(char *string1, char *string2);

int main()
{ 
  char string1[] = "The independent country is not only self-governed nation with own authorities.";
  char string2[] = "This status needs the international diplomatic recognition of sovereignty.";

  display_columns(string1,string2);
}

void display_columns(char *string1, char *string2)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     for(j=0+20*i;j<20+20*i;j++)
     {
       printf("%c",string1[j]);
     }

     printf("\t");

     for(j=0+20*i;j<20+20*i;j++)
     {
       printf("%c",string2[j]);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: These are `warnings`, not `errors`.

Comment: @Fahad, edited! However, the program doesn't want to respond. It just gives me output "Segmentation fault" after compiling and running.

Comment: If you want to print a single character, use `printf("%c",string1[j]);` - This is the reason for the warnings and segmentation fault.

Comment: Get the length of each string with `strlen()` (must `#include <string.h>`) and keep track of the number of chars printed, or remaining. Replace the outer `for` loop with a `while` loop checking that one of both strings have some characters remaining.

Comment: @nnn Thanks! Now it prints out my strings according to specification. However, this will not work with an unknown length since the program now prints out other stuff.

Comment: Oh and you forgot to printf a `newline`.

Comment: But please don't correct errors in the posted code in response to comments, it makes them hard to follow without looking back through the edits.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks a lot, I am however not quite sure what you are meaning, if you could put it into code it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Carl why not have a go yourself? Sorry about the typo, it was meant to read "checking that one ***or*** both strings have some characters remaining".

Comment: @WeatherVane regarding the editing of the code in response to comments: got it, won't happen again! I am a newbie here haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is more generic way to do it.

```
void print_line(char *str, int *counter) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (str[*counter] != '\0') {
            printf("%c", str[*counter]);
            *counter += 1;
        } 
        else { printf(" "); }
    }
}

void display_columns(char *string1, char *string2)
{
    int counter = 0, counter2 = 0;

    while (1) {

        print_line(string1, &counter);

        printf("\t");

        print_line(string2, &counter2);

        printf("\n");

        if (string1[counter] == '\0' && string2[counter2] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To print a single character, use:

```
printf("%c",string1[j]);
```

or

```
putchar(string1[j]);
```

This is the reason for the warnings and segmentation fault.

With this fix, the program somewhat works, you just have to print a newline as the last part of the loop:

```
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
     for(j=0+20*i;j<20+20*i;j++)
     {
       putchar(string1[j]);
     }

     printf("\t");

     for(j=0+20*i;j<20+20*i;j++)
     {
       putchar(string2[j]);
     }
     putchar('\n');
  }
```

**Update**: For the function to work with strings of variable lengths, try this:

```
void display_columns(char *string1, char *string2)
{
  int i,j;
  int len1 = strlen(string1);
  int len2 = strlen(string2);
  int maxlen = (len1 > len2) ? len1 : len2;
  int numloops = (maxlen + 20 - 1) / 20;
  for(i=0; i<numloops; i++)
  {
     for(j=0+20*i;j<20+20*i;j++)
     {
       if (j < len1)
           putchar(string1[j]);
       else
           putchar(' '); // Fill with spaces for correct alignment
     }

     printf("\t");

     for(j=0+20*i;j<20+20*i;j++)
     {
       if (j < len2)
           putchar(string2[j]);
       else
           break; // Just exit from the loop for the right side
     }
     putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me halfway! I just need to know how to adapt the printing so it can print out strings of any length.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of implementation for variable string lengths,

Comment: Plus 1 for a clean compilation and working with longer strings.